# Is there any difference between inline and out of line constraints

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, constraints

Is there any difference in performance/memory between inline constraints (on the column named check constraint) and out of line or multi column constraint.

Example I have a table storing names and I don't want to allow blank values in first and last name columns, and I also want each of them to be unique (which doesn't really make sense for names but for the example its okay), is there any difference how I make the constraint?

I can do both constraints on the column inline like:

```sql
create table dbo.People(
    FirstName varchar(50) not null 
        constraint u_FirstName unique
        constraint ck_FirstName_cannot_be_blank check(FirstName <> ''),
    LastName varchar(50) not null 
        constraint u_LastName unique
        constraint ck_LastName_cannot_be_blank check(LastName <> '')
)
```

Or I can do it with a comma separating the `unique` and `check` constraints (which makes it the same as out-of-line constraint) like:

```sql
create table dbo.People(
    FirstName varchar(50) not null 
        constraint u_FirstName unique,
        constraint ck_FirstName_cannot_be_blank check(FirstName <> ''),
    LastName varchar(50) not null 
        constraint u_LastName unique,
        constraint ck_LastName_cannot_be_blank check(LastName <> '')
)
```

Is there any difference between them on performance? And what about combining both check constraints like:

```sql
create table dbo.People(
    FirstName varchar(50) not null 
        constraint u_FirstName unique,
    LastName varchar(50) not null 
        constraint u_LastName unique,
    constraint ck_LastName_cannot_be_blank check(FirstName <> '' and LastName <> '')
)
```

I understand that the last one might not be preferred as it won't tell me what column is the issue, but does it effect the performance/memory of the table?

I'm asking because I did see some people doing the second way. Is it a costly mistake?

Comment: Both cases are the same and "inline" - you specify the constraints on the columns themselves, which is why you don't have to specify the column name.

Comment: I'm talking about the check constraints not the unique

Comment: FWIW I would use `> ''` instead of not equals.

Comment: There's no difference. It's just different syntax and definitely not "out of line". I don't know what you mean by that, but I'd consider an `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT` to be the out-of-line version. The syntax doesn't affect the way the constraint is implemented

Comment: @SeanLange I'm usually using for myself `> ''` but here for SO I decided to write `<> ''` because people shouldn't say I should use `<> ''`. But I see it didn't help ;)

Comment: I personally dislike that combined constraint at it is very odd. Logically it does the same thing but it can also leave you in a bad spot. If the requirement is that FirstName <> '' and the constraint is on LastName consider what happens if the LastName column is removed. It leaves your FirstName column with no constraint at all.

Comment: I must admit, there are times when I wish there was a `NOT BLANK`/`NOT EMPTY` type of syntax for string based data types, that didn't allow `NULL` or `''` values.

Comment: @ThomA Definitely, and it should be with a good error message like `not null` error message not like `primary key`.

Comment: @ThomA a `MinLength` would be the best of both worlds. If set to 1 it would ensure a character at a minimum. But for those oddball times you need a string to be "at least x characters" it would be pretty helpful.

Comment: If you want to know if there are performance differences between two implementations then... measure it; you could have easily determined an answer by now.

Comment: Yeah, `MINLENGTH` would also solve that, @SeanLange . In fact, I think I prefer `MINLENGTH` and then you could still define the column as `NULL`able. `MyColumn varchar(10) NULL MINLENGTH 5`. Though you could have `NOT NULL NOT BLANK` I suppose (but I don't like the look of that).

Comment: @ThomA yep. That is exactly where I was going with that. ;)

Comment: The combined case is different than the single column case. When it references multiple columns SQL Server does not consider this during simplification https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/329754/single-predicate-check-constraint-gives-constant-scan-but-two-predicate-constrai/329758#329758 - for a single column constraint it makes no odds if you declare it next to the column or as a table constraint. It gets treated the same metadata wise

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith this is actually the answer I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to flag as duplicate by referring to dba.stackexchange.com, so I'm posting it as answer here.

As [@Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) said in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76962129/is-there-any-difference-between-inline-and-out-of-line-constraints#comment135674141_76962129). This question is answered in [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/329758/242033).

The point of that answer by [Paul White](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/paul-white) is that when a constraint is declared on a single column, it will always be treated the same.

> For clarity, it doesn't matter which syntax is used to declare or add the constraint. A check constraint declared at table level, but which references only a single column, will be considered a column-level constraint. Likewise, a check constraint referencing only a single column added after table creation will be added as a column-level constraint.

So for my question the first and second tables are considered to be the same, and both are column-level constraints.

**One benefit of not using commas**

Adding to my old answer, I can see a benefit of not using commas when adding the constraint after the column that sometimes the IntelliSense will finish the column name for you when you make a check constraint, and this might cause unexpected behaviour if it inserts a wrong column name.

Example you have a column FirstName and a column LastName and you are adding the constraint not to allow blank in LastName but the IntelliSense inserts the FirstName by mistake, you don't realise and you can now insert blanks into LastName. This will only happen when you use commas, because when you don't add a comma before the constraint SQL will return an error for referencing a different column.